# Using embedded javascript to style HTML element displays error in VS Code

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, ejs

In my EJS file I am changing the border color of every even numbered row in a table using the following code:

```
<tr style="<% if (i % 2 == 0) { %> border: 3px solid crimson; <% }; %>" >
```

When I run my node.js web application this works as expected, the issue is that in VSCode it is showing that there are errors as displayed in the picture below:

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of this error or does VS Code just not recognize EJS syntax?

Comment: Posting images makes it really hard for people to help with your problem.

Comment: @Pointy sorry, why is that?

Comment: For one thing it is impossible to copy/paste code for inclusion into answers and comments. In this particular case, the error you say you're getting is not even visible. Read the site guidelines about posting good questions.

Comment: @Pointy I understand that, but in this case there is no need to copy paste any code from the pictures I am simply showing that VSCode seems to be displaying there is a syntax error. I'm not sure if you actually looked at the question but I did provide the actual code that is causing the syntax error so that it can be copy/pasted ...

Comment: I'm not a VS Code user, so this may not be the best option, just the first one that came up in google for "EJS support VS Code": https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DigitalBrainstem.javascript-ejs-support

Comment: @DanielBeck I have tried that, doesn't seem to work. It's weird because for the most part VS Code doesn't have a problem with the ejs syntax, it's just when it is inside of html style tags or if I use it inside ```<script>``` tags